# Adding, reusing and removing NSLayoutAnchors

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift2

So I have a *container* view (that is docked to the edges of the screen) and a *child* view that's supposed to slide in and out of it.

```
func slideOut() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(0.5), animations: {
        self.container.bottomAnchor
               .constraintEqualToAnchor(self.child.bottomAnchor).active = false
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func slideIn() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(0.5), animations: {
        self.container.bottomAnchor
               .constraintEqualToAnchor(self.child.bottomAnchor).active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    print("numConstraints: \(container.constraints.count)")
}
```

The `slideIn()` animation is fine, just as it's supposed to be. The problem is I don't know how to do the `slideOut()` animation. If I just deactivate the `NSLayoutConstraint` like above, then nothing happens. If instead I try:

```
self.container.bottomAnchor
       .constraintEqualToAnchor(self.child.topAnchor).active = true
```

then there is a warning about being unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints *and* nothing happens visually.
Also, whenever I make a `NSLayoutConstraint` active, the number of constraints (`print(container.constraints.count)`) increases, which can't be a good thing.

So my questions are:

1. How do I do a reverse of the `slideIn()` animation in this case?
2. How do I reuse the existing constraints in case of repeated animations so that the number of constraints doesn't add up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `constraintEqualToAnchor` method creates a new constraint. 
So when you're calling `self.container.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.child.bottomAnchor)` in the slide-out function you're not using the constraint you added in the `slideIn` method.

To achieve the desired slide-out animation you would have to keep a reference to the previous constraint. I'm not sure what the effect of setting the `.active` property on the constraint would be in the slide-out function since I don't know how your view hierarchy is set up.
But one way of reusing the constraint would be holding it as a var property in your VC:

```
lazy var bottomConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = self.container.bottomAnchor
        .constraintEqualToAnchor(self.child.bottomAnchor)

func slideOut() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(0.5), animations: {
        self.bottomConstraint.active = false
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func slideIn() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(0.5), animations: {
        self.bottomConstraint.active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    print("numConstraints: \(container.constraints.count)")
}
```

From Apple Docs:

> Activating or deactivating the constraint calls addConstraint: and removeConstraint: on the view that is the closest common ancestor of the items managed by this constraint.

So the reason why you're seing the increased number of constraints is because you keep creating new ones and adding them by setting `active` to true.

Comment: I was trying to change a UIScrollView contentSize by updating its latest subview bottom constraint with anchors. Deactivating, changing and reactivating it did the work. Thanks for this answer because it would have been difficult to guess what to do without it.